# how to get the values after five digits value in a column

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table

```
A
--
id    postalcode       pid
==========================
1     50631464     
2     454216454
3     4664646789
4     45643466464
```

I want to update pid column using postalcode get the values of postcode after five digit and remove the value after five digit in a postalcode push that value into pid column

So the result should be:

```
id       postalcode        pid                     
===============================
1      50631               464
2      45421               6454
3      46646               46789
4      45643               466464
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update the_table
   set postalcode = left(postalcode, 5),
       pid = substr(postalcode, 6);
```